# How to create procedure in PostgreSQL that displays rows and stores data?

Tags: postgresql, function, jdbc

I have been stuck for while trying to create procedure in PostgreSQL that returns a rows and stores a value:
(my code is wrong and is not correct) I did not find any clear guide to what I should do to fix it.

I need to print records and store the number of rows in Total (also how do I call a PostgreSQL procedure?)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE EMP(max_base_salary integer,out total integer )
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS  $BODY$
DECLARE 
BEGIN
    select count (*) from employees INTO total where base_salary<=max_base_salary;
    
    select * from employees where base_salary<=max_base_salary;

END;
$BODY$;
```

Comment: if you want to return something, use a function, not a procedure

Comment: do you have any soultion that could help me

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to return both the total and the records. Here is an example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION EMP(max_base_salary integer) RETURNS SETOF employees
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS  $BODY$
DECLARE 
BEGIN
    
    RETURN QUERY select * from employees where base_salary<=max_base_salary;

END;
$BODY$;
```

`SETOF` is set to the table and the `RETURN QUERY` is used to match the query results to the `SETOF`.